# Can an XML document follow both a DTD and an XML Schema?

Tags: xml, schema, dtd

Is it legal for an XML document to specify that it follows both a DTD **and** a Schema?
Won't the two conflict with one another?

Comment: In my case, I have an assignment question that asks me to write a DTD and a Schema for an XML document written earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically I think you would have problems with the DTD not recognizing the attributes for referencing the schema (the namespace declaration and the schema location).

However I think it depends on how you're validating your XML and whether or not you can ignore the DTD for validation if a schema is specified.

Also, for your assignment are you sure you have to reference both from the same XML instance? Maybe you could have 2 versions of the XML; one that references the DTD and one that references the schema?

---

Here's two other possible options...

**Declaring the schema attributes:**

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ELEMENT doc (test)>
<!ATTLIST doc
          xmlns:xsi CDATA #IMPLIED
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT test (#PCDATA)>
]>
<doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <test>Test Doc</test>
</doc>
```

**Using a processing instruction to reference the schema:**

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ELEMENT doc (test)>
<!ELEMENT test (#PCDATA)>
]>
<?xml-model href="test.xsd"?>
<doc>
    <test>Test Doc</test>
</doc>
```

Comment: Yes I suppose I can copy the XML file and use a separate one for the Schema portion

Comment: The namespace declaration can be included in the DTD (if you leave it out, XHTML documents are invalid when run through a DTD validator… e.g. *Missing xmlns attribute for element html. The value should be: `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`*). The processing instruction to link a schema to an XML document is a PI and thus not considered during validation.

Comment: @Quentin - That would be a good thing to add to your answer instead of assuming that the OP knows exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: Speculating about why the OP thinks that the two might conflict could lead to some very long answers :) (And if you wanted to use the xsi namespace to link a schema to a document, then you could allow or mandate that in a DTD too)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it legal for an XML document to specify that it follows both a DTD and a Schema?

Yes

> Won't the two conflict with one another?

Only if one of them mandates something the other forbids (in which case claiming to follow both would be a strange thing to do).

Comment: What I meant by "won't they conflict" is won't the statement in the XML document that declares it an instance of a schema conflict with its definition under the DTD?